# Step with scipy integrator without going past final point

Tags: python, scipy

The scipy integrators take two parameters when integrating: (1) `step` which tells the integrator to take only a single step, and (2) `relax` which tells the integrator that it is fine to step past the final time point.

I want to take steps (so that I can collect the entire solution), but also not step past the final time (because I have a discontinuity in my real problem). However, `step` being `True` seems to ignore `relax` being `False`. It will take one step over the final time with abandon.

Here is a simple example illustrating the problem:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

obj = ode(lambda t, y: -y)  # Simple exponential decay
obj.set_initial_value(4.0)

final_time = 2.0

ts_new = []
ys_new = []

# Take one step at a time until the final time is reached
while obj.t < final_time:
    y_new = obj.integrate(final_time, step=True, relax=False)

    ts_new.append(obj.t)
    ys_new.append(y_new)

print(ts_new[-1])  # 2.073628416585726
```

I would have expected the last step to be a partial step (is that what it's called?) and stop exactly on `final_time`, such as the value given by `obj.integrate(final_time, step=False, relax=False)`. Other than rerunning the entire ODE, is there a way to get the last point? I would be fine with setting `step` to `False` just before the last step, but I see no way to know if it will step over the final time until it does.

Comment: What do you expect it to do when you want to take a single step but you can't, because that's beyond the final time? It makes sense that these two options are incompatible. But looking at your code: why not just let it take that final step, but check in the loop after calling `integrate` and throw away the final point? What am I missing?

Comment: When `relax` is `False`, it doesn't stop before `final_time`, it stops exactly on it. When `step` is `True`, I would have expected it to still take a partial step and stop exactly on `final_time`. (Question edited to reflect this.)

Comment: Does your discontinuity at `final_time` not affect the solution at exactly that point? And how big is the difference there: can't you use a final Euler-step or something to solve for the final time value? You could also try setting the `min_step`, `max_step` parameters of `vode` (the [default integrator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html))

Comment: My final time is actually a small delta before the discontinuity, so it doesn't affect it exactly at that point, but it is important to not step over the time. I have thought about throwing away the last point and restarting, but that still steps over and might trigger an error. The max step is a good idea and might work if I can avoid floating point subtraction issues.

Answer (score 0):

A bad solution is to set the `max_step` to `final_time - obj.t` at each step. It is tempting because it does actually work, but the performance is horrendous.

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

obj = ode(lambda t, y: -y)  # Simple exponential decay
obj.set_initial_value(4.0)

final_time = 2.0

ts_new = []
ys_new = []

# Take one step at a time until the final time is reached
while obj.t < final_time:
    obj.set_integrator('vode', max_step=final_time-obj.t)
    y_new = obj.integrate(final_time, step=True, relax=False)

    ts_new.append(obj.t)
    ys_new.append(y_new)

print(ts_new[-1])  # 2.0
```

Note that it stops at the correct time. However, it appears that the call to `set_integrator` rebuilds the integrator, which causes a colossal slowdown. It takes 27 steps to integrate the system in the question, but 36215 steps to integrate the system in this answer. It is not possible to avoid rebuilding the integrator by directly mutating `obj._integrator.max_step`, as this appears to be a copy of the Fortran parameter and has no effect on the integration.

Answer (score 0):

A passable solution is to throw away the point that steps over the final time and create an fresh integrator that starts at the penultimate time and integrates `step=False` to the final time. I have not timed it, but I suspect that this is also somewhat expensive.

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

obj = ode(lambda t, y: -y)  # Simple exponential decay
obj.set_initial_value(4.0)

final_time = 2.0

ts_new = []
ys_new = []

# Take one step at a time until the final time is reached
while obj.t < final_time:
    y_new = obj.integrate(final_time, step=True, relax=False)

    if obj.t <= final_time:
        ts_new.append(obj.t)
        ys_new.append(y_new)
    else:
        t_last = ts_new[-1]
        obj = ode(lambda t, y: -y)
        obj.set_initial_value(ys_new[-1], t_last)
        y_new = obj.integrate(final_time, step=False, relax=False)
        ts_new.append(obj.t)
        ys_new.append(y_new)

print(ts_new[-1])  # 2.0
```

Note that it gives the correct final time. This does not protect against errors during integration caused by stepping over the discontinuity, so those will have to be caught in production software to trigger the bonus step.

There are undoubtedly some extra steps as the bonus integrator revs up, but those are quietly tossed away by `step=False`. I tried to set `min_step` to something approximately equal to the full distance to final time to give it a hint, but that just blew up the integrator.